# How to combine two tables that doesn't have common columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to combine two tables into one  which show columns from both table? One of my table is regular table and from this table I need to feed value to another table which is scalar valued function take as a parameter.

For e.g.

```
T1 -> | c1 | c2 | c3 | 
  ________________

T2 -> fnGetValue(@c1) -> one column table
```

I need to combine these two tables but c1 needs to pass as a parameter to get the value from T2.

Comment: So, wich one is it?, a scalar valued function or a table valued function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `fnGetValue` is a table valued function then you can use the [`APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t2.*
from table1 t1
outer apply fnGetValue(t1.c1) t2
```

From the [MSDN Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> OUTER APPLY returns both rows that produce a result set, and rows that do not, with NULL values in the columns produced by the table-valued function.

If the `fnGetValue` is a scalar function, then you should be able to use:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, fnGetValue(t1.c1) as Value
from table1 t1
```